# Who is the single most powerful entity in the marvel universe?

Tags: marvel

Okay, I know this might be a really stupid question to ask, but I have always been on the look out for the being to whole the title "most powerful" and when I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNLqEl0qgbE) I got curious as to who would fit the bill in the Marvel universe.

I have looked into characters such as [Thanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos), [Umar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umar_(Marvel_Comics)), [Mephisto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mephisto_(comics)), [Dormammu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormammu), [Beyonder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonder), [Puma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puma_(comics)), and [Surtur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surtur_(Marvel_Comics)), all of which listed some way that they could be destroyed.

So, my question is two-fold. Who, in the Marvel Multi-verse, A) has the greatest power and B) the smallest (preferably non-existent) weakness?

Comment: how are you measuring "greatest power" and "smallest weakness"

Comment: @Richard Aha, I was looking for that one!

Comment: Isn't it Stan Lee?  ;-)

Comment: [One-Above-All](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/One-Above-All_(Multiverse))